# C++, boost: which is fastest way to parse string like tcp://adr:port/ into address string and one int for port?

Tags: c++, string, boost, tcp

we have std::string `A` with `tcp://adr:port/` How to parse it into address std::string and one int for port?

Comment: fastest? just do a custom parser. this can be done in linear scan time.

Comment: Just a thought: you may want to support service names for ports (e.g. telnet=23, http=80).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void extract(std::string const& ip, std::string& address, std::string& service)
{
   boost::regex e("tcp://(.+):(\\d+)/");
   boost::smatch what;
   if(boost::regex_match(ip, what, e, boost::match_extra))
   {
     boost::smatch::iterator it = what.begin();
     ++it; // skip the first entry..
     address = *it;
     ++it;
     service = *it;
   }
}
```

EDIT: reason service is a string here is that you'll need it as a string for resolver! ;)

Comment: Nice and clean, but definitely won't be the fastest like that as the regex is recompiled on every call.  Maybe it could be static, but then there's thread safety issues (even if using GCC - hence thread-safe local static construction - I can't remember if boost::regex is safe, but might be as boost::smatch could be the only thing mutated during regex_match).  Still, if "fastest" really is the requirement (unlikely, as the time to decode this string is trivial compared to any connection attempt), then would want to benchmark this against `sscanf`.

Comment: hmm.. so ip is adr and service is port?

Comment: @Tony, I'd hazard that the performance of this is not what the OP was looking for! ;) more, what is the quickest way of getting it done! :) @Kambumbus, yes...

Answer (score 9):

Although some wouldn't consider it particularly kosher C++, probably the *easiest* way would be to use sscanf:

```
sscanf(A.c_str(), "tcp://%[^:]:%d", &addr, &port);
```

Another possibility would be to put the string into a stringstream, imbue the stream with a facet that treats most alphabetic and punctuation as whitespace, and just read the address and port like:

```
std::istringstream buffer(A);
buffer.imbue(new numeric_only);
buffer >> addr >> port;
```

The facet would look something like this:

```
struct digits_only: std::ctype<char> 
{
    digits_only(): std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        // everything is white-space:
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> 
            rc(std::ctype<char>::table_size,std::ctype_base::space);

        // except digits, which are digits
        std::fill(&rc['0'], &rc['9'], std::ctype_base::digit);

        // and '.', which we'll call punctuation:
        rc['.'] = std::ctype_base::punct;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

`operator>>` treats whitespace as separators between "fields", so this will treat something like `192.168.1.1:25` as two strings: "192.168.1.1" and "25".

Comment: tsk tsk tsk... OP wants string and int... ;)

Comment: @Jerry, you missed `c_` in `c_str`. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: +1 for the scanf. Also mentioning the Facets was nice, but in my opinion they just look ugly and unmantainable code

Comment: the IP or hostname is not a single number - you can't use `%d` format, rather, isn't it `%*[^:]` where `*` is provided with a maximum buffer size to avoid potential overrun?

Comment: @Tony: yes, probably. Changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest as in computer time or programmer time?  I can't speak of benchmarks but the uri library in the cpp-netlib framework works very well and is very easy and straightforward to use.

http://cpp-netlib.github.com/0.8-beta/uri.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool like [re2c](http://re2c.org/) to create a fast custom scanner.  I'm also unclear on what you consider to be "fastest" -- for the processor or development time or both?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays one may also meet IPv6 addresses with a host part that already contains a variable number of colons and dots. Splitting URL's then should be done following [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). See [wikipedia IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)