# finding characters between integers

Tags: c++

i wanna make a progarm with c++ that take input from one file that contains information 
like this:

```
physic 17
math 20
programming 10
```

if i want give integer in this file and i don't want characters like physic and etc
what libraray should i include and what function should i use

Answer (score 1):

When you use file stream like [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/) and reading to string, you get one word from the stream.
So try creating fstream s and:

```
fstream s("file.txt",ios::in);
string word;
int number;
s >> word;
s >> number;
// do something with 17 (you got it in number variable)
s >> word;
s >> number;
// do something with 20 (you got it in number variable)
//and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

Until the end of file -

1. `std::getline` from the file. ( `fstream` to perform file operations )
2. `strtok` the read string ( i.e., read line from the file ) based on space delimeter until end of line. ( `cstring` )
3. Convert the second token to integer using `atoi`. ( `cstdlib` )

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your on function for this. But I recall scanf having the ability to filter out characters/numbers by specifying the type.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this with the digits_only facet I posted in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210567/boost-which-is-fastest-way-to-parse-string-like-tcp-adrport-into-adress/4210594#4210594). The sequence would look like:

```
std::ifstream infile("whatever.txt");
infile.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new digits_only());

std::vector<int> numbers;
int temp;

while (infile >> temp)
    numbers.push_back(temp); // or use std::copy, if you prefer
```