# how to stop while loop running for storing data in vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector, stl

i am using while loop for storing integer data in a vector like this :

```
vector<int> a;
int data=1;
cout<<"Enter data (Press Ctrl+Z to end)";

while(data)
        {
            cin>>data;
            if(data)
                a.push_back(data);
        }
```

this loop goes infinite the reason i found out after tacing is that when i enter `Ctrl+Z (eof)` to read in `data` it does not take that value and because last value is still there in `data` the loop runs again

```
Enter data (Press Ctrl+Z to end)23 //data=23
56 //data=56
45 //data=45
^Z // still data=45
```

i don't want to use condition with a specific number to end the loop like `Enter -1 to end` and user to specify the number of items to store in vector in advance. Is there any other way i can end the loop by using `Ctrl+Z` or any other string like `done, finish etc..`

Comment: Where you check for CTRL-Z?! If you don't then your loop won't stop. Moreover you're reading TO an int then stream won't write there special characters and strings...

Comment: so read in the value as a string instead of an int.  Check the value for some special escape string, and not matched convert to an int.

Comment: your program will stop if you enter `0`, and on linux it will stop/suspend the process when you press `ctrl + z`. i'm not quite sure what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Adriano how can i check when it is not replacing the last given value to `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(cin >> data){
    a.push_back(data);
}
```

Note that the EOF is usually set by using Ctrl+D, not Ctrl+Z (which will instead let your program sleep).

Comment: Doesn't this stop even if user enters "please quit this loop"?

Comment: @Adriano: It stops as soon as the extraction fails. If extraction fails, there weren't only integers in our stream. Therefore, our input might not even be valid to begin with.

Comment: LOL it was just a joke!

Answer (score 2):

I'd skip the loop and read the data with a pair of `istream_iterator`s:

```
cout<<"Enter data (Press Ctrl+Z to end)";

std::vector<int> a{std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                   std::istream_iterator<int>()};
```

Note that this will stop reading when it reaches the end of the input *or* it encounters something that can't be converted to an `int` (e.g., any character other than a digit or white-space).

If you really need to read all input (and convert numbers where you find them), you have a couple of choices. One I'd probably use would be to create a [ctype facet that classifies everything except digits as white space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4210594/179910), so the istream will just ignore everything except the numbers.

Another possibility (that some people might find more straightforward, even though it'll probably be more complex) is to read a line at a time with `std::getline`, then search in that string for a digit and convert that group of digits to an `int`. This gets particularly ugly if you might have more than one `int` on a line, so you need to re-start your search for digits after the end of the one you just converted.

Also note that <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> only works on Windows, and isn't even particularly dependable there. You normally want to use <kbd>F6</kbd> instead. For <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to work, you need to use <kbd>enter</kbd> <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

> if(data)
>       a.push_back(data);

This is flawed because if you input 0 the if will evaluate as false.