# Parse a text file until a float is found?

Tags: c++, parsing

I am trying to parse lines from a text file. Each row represents a stock ticker and has the same format, having a random number of strings(for the company name + symbol) followed by uniform number of floats (same amount for each line).

How would you check if the last read string is a float to know when I have reached the end of the strings and to start parsing the floats?

Sample lines of text:

```
A.M. CASTLE & COMPANY CAS 15.71 0.55  3.63 31.57 17.97 8.99 7.79
AAR CORP AIR 17.79 0.19  1.08 30.62 18.45 10.51 38.26 
ABBOTT LABORATORIES ABT 45.14 0.01  0.02 -3.24 50.00 40.25 20.33
```

Sample Code:

```
void parse(string filename){
    ifstream myfile;        
    string line;
    string current_word;

    myfile.open(filename);
    if (myfile.is_open()){
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            stringstream current_line(line);
            while (current_line >> current_word){
                // How can I test when I have reached a float here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of current attempt in your question so we have better idea of exactly what you're doing. This will help us provide a suitable answer.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that no digits will appear before the first floating point number?

Comment: Yes, it will be only letters or punctuation (hyphens, parenthesis, ampersands, etc) in the strings before the floats are reached.

Comment: I would use the `digits_only` facet I posted in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4210594/179910). That was reading `int` instead of `float` data, but accommodating that change is pretty trivial (just change the items you read from `int` to `float`--the facet isn't affected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the stream reading of the number to see if it succeeded and use the value if it did like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::string line = "A.M. CASTLE & COMPANY CAS 15.71 0.55 3.63 31.57 17.97 8.99 7.79";

    std::istringstream iss(line); // convert the line into a stream

    std::string item;
    while(iss >> item) // read the stream items (space separated) one by one
    {
        float f;
        if(std::istringstream(item) >> f) // does this item read as a float?
        {
            // use f here if it does
            std::cout << f << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed that none of the strings before the float will contain a digit, then you can simply compare each character until a digit is found, and you have found the first character of the float.

Without that guarantee, I would probably parse words. This is a trivial matter of adding each character to a string until whitespace is found. If that string contains only digits and a single period, then you've found your float. Otherwise, skip over to the next non-whitespace character, and do the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf()`, which will do the requested operation in one line.

```
bool parseNameAndFloats(char const *input, char *name, unsigned int namesize, float *floatArray, unsigned int floatsize)
{
    // Assuming the sample string is representative, there's 7 floats in it.
    if (floatsize < 7)
    {
        return false;
    }
    char *temp = strdup(input);
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        // deal with allocation failure in strdup;
        return false;
    }
    int count = sscanf(input, "%[^0-9.]s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", temp, floatArray, floatArray + 1, floatArray + 2, floatArray + 3, floatArray + 4,floatArray + 5, floatArray + 6);
    if (namesize > 0)
    {
        strncpy(name, temp, namesize);
        name[namesize - 1] = 0;
    }
    free(temp);
    return count == 8;
}
```

There are those that will criticize `sscanf()`, and when used incorrectly it can cause some major problems.  One such is the reason I use `strdup()` to make a copy of the original input string.  That's guaranteed to get me a buffer big enough to hold the results of the `%[^0-9.]s` conversion.  I then use `strncpy()` to extract no more than will fit in the provided buffer, and make sure to [NUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions available in C++11.

Double-check the pattern for floating-point numbers. E.g. my expression does not allow a leading sign.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream input("A.M. CASTLE & COMPANY CAS 15.71 0.55 3.63 31.57 17.97 8.99 7.79");

    // Pattern for recognizing floating-point numbers
    std::regex pattern(R"(\d+\.(\d*)?((e|E)(\+|\-)?\d+)?)");

    for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line); )
    {
        // We have a successful read of one line
        // Now extract the floating-point numbers on that line

        auto first = std::sregex_iterator(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), pattern);
        auto last = std::sregex_iterator();
        for (; first != last; ++first)
        {
            double d = std::stof(first->str());
            std::cout << d << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```